# powermockito - testing exception handling

Tags: java, powermockito

Testing a snip:

```
void somefunction() {
  try {
    aMock.doSomething();
    bMock.another();
  } finally {
    cMock.cleanup();
  }
}
```

Test:

```
@Test(expected = Exception.class)
void sometest() {
  ... setup various mocks ...

  PowerMockito.doThrow(new Exception("abc")).when(aMock).doSomething();

  outerMock.somefunction();

  // ** THIS SHOULD FAIL
  verify(bMock).another();

  // ** THIS SHOULD FAIL TOO
  verify(cMock, never()).cleanup()
}
```

When I run this it passes. Why? Does the throw Exception (and handling in @Test) trump the **verify** statements?

If so - is there some way to test that the **finally** clause was executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the exception is thrown (for real), everything under your function code is dead code.

```
outerMock.somefunction();  // throw so, this is the end

// ------- dead code blow:
// ** THIS SHOULD FAIL
verify(bMock).another();

// ** THIS SHOULD FAIL TOO
verify(cMock, never()).cleanup()
```

So to test the finally block you have to use a normal execution (when no exception occurs). Another solution would be to use a try/catch in the test:

```
try {
    outerMock.somefunction();
    fail("was expecting an exception..");
} catch(Exception exception) {
    // ignore
}

verify(bMock).another();
verify(cMock, never()).cleanup()
```

---

To answer to the question in comments:

assuming the code is now:

```
void somefunction() {
    try {
        aMock.doSomething();
        bMock.another();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        cMock.handleException(ex);
    }
}
```

the test could be:

```
Exception testEx = new Exception("testing")
Mockito.when(aMock.doSomething()).thenThrow(testEx);
instance.somefunction();
Mockito.verify(cMock).handleException(testEx);
```

Comment: Is there a way to have this work if there is a 'catch()' instead of a 'finally' ?

Comment: If there is a catch in your production code, then no exception is thrown and there is no problem, what do you mean?

Comment: verifying the actions / results of the code in the catch() block.

Comment: the action in a catch block can be verified the same way any code is I will add an example as an edit

Comment: Thanks for the update / edit. Thats the path I was expecting but not what Im seeing. There must be some problem with my code.